# How to generate a QR code for end user payment?

Tags: payment-processing, upi

We have a requirement to provide UPI payments for our users, we tried the google pay APIs, but it shows the pay button, and also it supports only google pay, we need to support other payment apps as well.

I was planning to generate a QR code with the amount pre-filled.
for example: If I buy a sandwich, the bill might be 100 rs, and the QR code must be generated for that only.

Comment: Do you have any **specific** question about this? Generating a QR code is not that hard and well documented in tons of tutorials

Comment: The question is to generate a upi payment QR, which when scanned can deduct the specific order amount.

Comment: That is not a question, but a requirement. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3):

You can generate QR code by creating the QR for specific intent.

```
upi://pay?pa=&pn=&am=&cu=&tn=

where:
pa = Payee address or business virtual payment address (VPA).
pn = Payee name or business name.
am = Transaction amount.
cu = Currency Code.
tn = Transaction note.
```

Converting this to QR will enable to make payments using any UPI App.
Eg:

```
upi://pay?pa=anything%40payu&pn=Foody&tn=Order&am=100.34&cu=INR
```

Javascript code to generate links:

```js
let upi = {
    pa: "anything@payu",
    pn: "Foody",
    tn: "Order",
    am: "100.34",
    cu: "INR"
}
let upiLink = new URLSearchParams(upi).toString();
```